# How to change UILabel text color based on the color of background image? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uilabel

I would like to change text color of UILabel based on the color of the background image. For example, change the color of UILabel text color to white when a dark background image is present and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach - It is not my work... I found it at https://gist.github.com/adamcichy/2d00c7a54009b4a9751ba513749c485e (re-posting it here, as links can fail in the future):

```
extension CGImage {
    var isDark: Bool {
        get {
            guard let imageData = self.dataProvider?.data else { return false }
            guard let ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData) else { return false }
            let length = CFDataGetLength(imageData)
            let threshold = Int(Double(self.width * self.height) * 0.45)
            var darkPixels = 0
            for i in stride(from: 0, to: length, by: 4) {
                let r = ptr[i]
                let g = ptr[i + 1]
                let b = ptr[i + 2]
                let luminance = (0.299 * Double(r) + 0.587 * Double(g) + 0.114 * Double(b))
                if luminance < 150 {
                    darkPixels += 1
                    if darkPixels > threshold {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    var isDark: Bool {
        get {
            return self.cgImage?.isDark ?? false
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use (for example):

```
    // default to false (meaning, the image is not dark)
    let b = myImageView.image?.isDark ?? false

    if b {
        // use a light-color for textColor
    } else {
        // use a dark-color for textColor
    }
```

It's not quite that simple though... Your image may have light and dark areas, so you would only want to calculate the image area that will be behind your label. But this is a good starting point.

**Edit:** As rmaddy commented, this may not give you the results you want. Images, particularly photographs, have varied light and dark pixels / areas. For example, you may have a dark building against a bright sky --- if the label begins on the building and ends on the sky, checking for the "darkness" of the bounding rectangle won't do you much good.

One alternative approach would be to use white text with a dark, semi-translucent rectangle (rounded-corners, soft edges) behind the text.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for general photographs. The area with the label can have both light and dark pixels. You can't just pick either light text or dark text and make it readable in all cases.